# Central admin-managed contact list for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, contacts.app

what is the solution to provide a group of iPhone users (personally owned devices with users own AppleIDs) with an group-contact list that is centrally managed by an admin (i.e. the group contact list on phone always being sync'ed with central admin version)? E.g. consultants in a workgroup being able to get hold of each other and ensuring contact list is always up-to-date.

Most existing contact-related apps don't seem to have admin/sync functionality to other accounts, just like they try to sync with contact list on the phone which should be an option but not a requirement. (examples on contact list are: ContactSync, Contacts Sync, Get Contacts, Circall, ContactBox, ZXContacts, aContacts+, ...).

A Google account and Contacts could be used for "admin service".

I have been unsuccessful trying to set up Google to delegate contacts, though this may solve some issues.

Has anyone had the same challenge before?

Thanks!

Rune

Comment: Be advised that you cannot take away the ability for anyone to "see" the list once you have granted them permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Rune,

Using [ContactBox][1] a person can share a list of contacts with a group of people/devices. By default anyone the list was shared with can update the list but the list admin (the person who created the list) can prevent the other group members from editing. Any changes made to the list are synched to all group members. What is synched is a list and not an "account" and you can create as many lists as you want and share each one with a different set of people.

Hope that helps, Gal
Disclosure: I the founder of ContactBox